# Production build with Vuejs3 and Vite

Tags: npm, vuejs3, vite

I've created a vuejs App with vite and with the local development Server everything is finde.

now i want to deploy the App under a Apache Webserver and get a blank page without error.

My index.html in dist:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>aM</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-8e9b77d6.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/@vue-c5631f51.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/vue-router-cb554bea.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/pinia-24020fcf.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/luxon-1af9332f.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/axios-4a70c6fc.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/crypto-js-629e539e.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/izitoast-40803d10.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/vuetify-bb88969c.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/@intlify-771bffe6.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/vue-i18n-b6b11f81.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/vue3-easy-data-table-ba1e6059.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/hookable-e7fd869b.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/@unhead-8e4406cf.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/unhead-c080450a.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/vue-country-flag-next-10f89852.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/@fortawesome-24306ca7.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/pinia-logger-5dea0034.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/izitoast-276cc841.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/vuetify-d07219f2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/vue3-easy-data-table-90b8d25d.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/index-7552c403.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/@mdi-dfac2f60.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

my vite-config.js:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url"

import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"

// https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-vue-setup-extend-plus
import inheritAttrs from "vite-plugin-vue-setup-inherit-attrs"
// https://github.com/xiaoxian521/vite-plugin-remove-console
import removeConsole from "vite-plugin-remove-console"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), splitVendorChunkPlugin(), inheritAttrs(), removeConsole()],
  base: './',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx", ".mjs", ".ts", ".tsx", ".vue"],
  },
  define: {
    __VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__: true,
    __VUE_I18N_LEGACY_API__: false,
    __INTLIFY_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
  },
  build: {
    // This is a work around and only hides warnings
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600,
    sourcemap: true,
    // outDir: "./wwwroot/app/",
    // Build Target
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-target
    target: "esnext",
    // Minify option
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-minify
    minify: "esbuild",
    // Rollup Options
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-rollupoptions
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        // entryFileNames: "[name].[hash].js",
        // chunkFileNames: "[name].[hash].js",
        // assetFileNames: "[name].[hash].[ext]",

        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
            return id.toString().split("node_modules/")[1].split("/")[0].toString()
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 80,
    // port: 5173,
    // port: 8000,
  },
  /*server: {
    port: 3000,
    hmr: {
      host: 'localhost',
    },
  },*/
})

// https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host
// https://openbase.com/js/unplugin-vue-setup-extend-plus

//testcommit
```

even if i run npm run build and then npm run preview i get an empty page with no error.

expected to see my application view

Answer (score -1):

put

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-8e9b77d6.js"></script>
```

after

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey there! thank you for your answer, unfortunatly that does not solve the problem

Comment: ok, check out you production index.js and see if something is missing at loading, I dont have enough info to help you for now